# What is a bfloat16_t in the C++23 standard?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++23

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdfloat) documents that `stdfloat` includes 5 new types: `float16_t`, `float32_t`, `float64_t`, `float128_t` and `bfloat16_t`. While the first 4 types are self-explanatory (a float with 16, 32, 64, and 128 bits respectively), the last type `bfloat16_t` is not at all clear to me. What does this type represent? What does the `b` in its name mean?

Comment: possibly: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101754/0618/armclang-Reference/Other-Compiler-specific-Features/BFloat16-floating-point-number-format#:~:text=for%20your%20feedback-,BFloat16%20floating%2Dpoint%20number%20format,It%20is%20supported%20by%20Armv8.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bfloat16_floating-point_format

Comment: Introduced by https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1467r9.html. For the specific properties of each type see https://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.extended.fp.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"bfloat16" refers to a [fairly recent 16-bit floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bfloat16_floating-point_format) that is *not* a valid IEEE-754/IEC 60559 defined format. But it is related to them.

BINARY16 is just BINARY32 with smaller numbers for its components. But the size changes are evenly distributed; it has both a smaller mantissa and a smaller exponent.

Bfloat16 opts for a different way to spend its 16 bits. It elects to keep the exponent the same size as BINARY32 (8-bit) while shrinking the mantissa down to 7-bits (explicit). This makes transforming between bfloat16 and BINARY32 a faster operation.

It does have some special-case weirdness, but overall, it's a truncated BINARY32. And while it's widely supported in a surprising amount of GPU hardware, it's not truly a standard.

The utility of bfloat16 comes down to two things: the speed of conversion, and the compromises of BINARY16.

BINARY16 is a great format... for colors. Having a maximum range of only 5 decimal orders of magnitude above zero is adequate for many cases of high-dynamic range rendering.

But this compromise is a problem for machine learning operations. If precision matters, you're going to have to spend 32-bits to get it. But if [precision isn't all that important](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/bfloat16-the-secret-to-high-performance-on-cloud-tpus), being able to save 16 bits without the range compromise can be useful in these applications.

Comment: The wikipedia page of BINARY16 shows a sign bit. Am I missing something? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: @Brotcrunsher: Good catch; I was thinking about other non-standard floating-point formats, like those use for RGB9E5 colors.